# Allow set in a subclass but not in another

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes `Folder` and `File`. They have a property `NumberFiles`. For `File`, it's of course only 1 at all case, for `Folder`, it depends how many files in the folder. This property must implement `RaisePropertyChanged` to bind.

I don't allow a set `NumberFiles` in `FileRecord`. But I can't find a solution, so this is my hack. With this code, I can set `NumberFiles`, but it doesn't have any effect.

```
public abstract class Record : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _numberFiles;
    public virtual int NumberFiles 
    {
        get
        {
            return _numberFiles;
        }
        set
        {
            _numberFiles= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(NumberFiles));
        }
    }

    //and a lot of properties
}

public class FolderRecord : Record
{
    //and a lot of properties
}

public class FileRecord : Record
{
    public override int NumberFiles 
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        } 
        set
        {
            //HACK : let empty SET
        }
    }
    //and a lot of properties
}

public Main()
{
        var list = new List<Record>(); // this list used to bind to the DataGrid
        Record rc;
        for (some condition)
        {
            if (folder)
            {
                rc = new RecordFolder();
                rc.NumberFiles = 10; // OK
            }
            else if (file)
            {
                rc = new FileRecord();
                rc.NumberFiles = 10; // the property NumberFiles can't allow a set, should compile error here  
            }
            list.Add(rc);
        }
}
```

I already have tried like put `protected set` in the base class but I can't set the value later.

Comment: Is it not working or are you looking for a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried having no set in the base class, and having the set defined only in the Folder class?  In the base, simply define the property as `public virtual int NumberFiles {get;} = 1`.  I think (but, I'm not sure), that you can add the setter in a sub-class

Comment: I think you need to revisit your design.  Why does `Record` have a number of files property? Why does a `FileRecord` derive from Record` when it isn't a `Record`.  Try googling for 'Is A' vs 'Has A' relationship.

Comment: I would throw an Exception instead of leaving it empty.

Comment: @itsme86 as I said in the question, I'm looking a better solution

Comment: @Neil the relation btw Record and FileRecord isn't relevant to the question. This question is about the inherit, get and set.

Comment: @AntoineV If it is okay to set the property on the base class, it should be okay to set it on the inherited class.  You're changing the contract specified by the base class.  That's a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.  Neil's point is valid and relevant.  Your model needs to be redesigned.

Comment: @Amy So, do you have a proposition about how to redesigned this ? The condition : FileRecord vs FolderRecord must inherit Record.

Comment: `NumberFiles` should not be a property on the base class if it doesn't apply to all of its inheritors.

Comment: @AntoineV Actually you said you can't find "a solution", that's why I asked.

Comment: @Amy I don't totally agree with this. Likes you write down the answer to let the others person juging it?

Comment: @AntoineV I'm not sure what there is to disagree on.  Good luck to you.

Comment: @Amy There is 2 reasons : 1. In my context, I need to bind the List<Record> mentionned in the question, if the property isn't on base class, when binding, how it works ? 2. All the inheritors have this property, for me, an inheritance is suitable in this case.

Answer (score -1):

```
public abstract class Record
{
    public abstract int GetNumberFiles();
}

public class FolderRecord : Record
{
    private int _numberOfFiles;

    public void SetNumberOfFiles(int numberOfFiles)
    {
        _numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles;
    }

    public override int GetNumberFiles()
    {
        return _numberOfFiles;
    }
}

public class FileRecord : Record
{
    public override int GetNumberFiles()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How I call RaisePropertyChanged when it's a method ??

Comment: Number of files can change only for `FolderRecord`, right ? So, add whatever logic you need to `SetNumberOfFiles` method.